# AutoIt Send() Not Working

Tags: autoit

```
Func OpenSHK()
   global $Loginx = 0, $Loginy = 0, $Playx = 0, $Playy = 0
   Run(@ProgramFilesDir & "\Stronghold Kingdoms\StrongholdKingdoms.exe")
   WinWaitActive("Stronghold Kingdoms")
      If WinExists("Stronghold Kingdoms") Then
         SendKeepActive("Stronghold Kingdoms")
      Else
         WinWait("Stronghold Kingdoms")
         SendKeepActive("Stronghold Kingdoms")
      EndIf
   Sleep(5000)
   Send("testphrase")
   Local $search = _ImageSearch('pics/LoginButton.bmp', 0, $Loginx, $Loginy, 0)
      If $search = 1 Then
         MouseMove($Loginx, $Loginy, 20)
         MouseClick("left")
      Else
         Do
            $search = _ImageSearch('pics/LoginButton.bmp', 0, $Loginx, $Loginy, 0)
            sleep(5000)
         Until $search = 1
         MouseMove($Loginx, $Loginy, 20)
         MouseClick("left")
      EndIf
   Sleep(5000)
      Local $search = _ImageSearch('pics/PlayButton.bmp', 0, $Playx, $Playy, 0)
      If $search = 1 Then
         MouseMove($Playx, $Playy, 20)
         MouseClick("left")
      Else
         Do
            $search = _ImageSearch('pics/PlayButton.bmp', 0, $Playx, $Playy, 0)
            sleep(5000)
         Until $search = 1
         MouseMove($Playx, $Playy, 20)
         MouseClick("left")
      EndIf
   WinWaitActive("Stronghold Kingdoms - World 8")
   sleep(10000)
EndFunc
```

The function works fine, until it reaches line 6. It does not send the test phrase, and I cannot seem to figure out why.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many errors in your code:

1. `Run("@ProgramFilesDir\Stronghold Kingdoms\StrongholdKingdoms.exe")`
   should be `Run(@ProgramFilesDir & "\Stronghold Kingdoms\StrongholdKingdoms.exe")`
2. That's why `winwaitactive` probably gets never passed. Try a loop instead to see if the window exists, rather than if it's active.
3. If the window exists you can activate it then or use `SendKeepActive` (I think that's what it's called.)

Comment: Ok, so I changed what you said, and made it a loop, but the Send function still isn't sending. I can type what it's supposed to be sending in just fine, but it is not sending. I'll upload the new code in one sec.

Comment: Uploaded new version in main post.

Comment: Is the window active when you use `send`?

Comment: I don't know why it should not work at all. I'm sorry I can't help you further.

Comment: Ah, I figured it out. Thanks for your help :P

Answer (score -1):

When I was working with AutoIt and having a similar problem (for the same program :) ), I think I ended up using controlsend, sometimes, and send at other times.
I also ended up going into the handles, and telling autoit to make specific text boxes active.